# Getting the number of filled cells in a column (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

My first column is an index, with monotonously increasing numbers, which ends at a non predictable point.
Now I want to find out, how many entries this column has. Is there a better way than iterating throug this and watch out for an empty cell?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way is to: (Assumes index column begins at A1)

```
MsgBox Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
```

Which is looking for the 1st unoccupied cell downwards from A1 and showing you its ordinal row number.

You can select the next empty cell with:

```
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
```

If you need the end of a dataset (including blanks), try: Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

Comment: It's better to do it like MrKowz below illustrates. If for some reason there is an empty row you could miss out on a lot of data.

Comment: In some cases, however this question specifically states its for filled cells, and miscounting due to non-contiguous cells can be just as bad

Answer (score 27):

If you want to find the last populated cell in a particular column, the best method is:

```
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

This code uses the very last cell in the entire column (65536 for Excel 2003, 1048576 in later versions), and then find the first populated cell above it.  This has the ability to ignore "breaks" in your data and find the true last row.

Comment: when I try to run this code I get an error saying that 'Rows' is not defined?

Answer (score 6):

You can also use

```
Cells.CurrentRegion
```

to give you a range representing the bounds of your data on the current active sheet

Msdn says on the topic

> Returns a Range object that represents
>   the current region. The current region
>   is a range bounded by any combination
>   of blank rows and blank columns.
>   Read-only.

Then you can determine the column count via

```
Cells.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
```

and the row count via

```
Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
```

Comment: There are so many different ways of doing this and some are adamantly supported as the right way, but this is the only thing that worked for me. My data is generated by software which apparently puts nulls in many cells beyond the last row of data, so 'UsedRange' failed. This solution is much simpler than any others provided.

Answer (score 4):

You may also use:

```
UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Answer (score 2):

To find the last filled column use the following :

```
lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```