# Importing data columns of unknown and varying length into matlab from excel

Tags: excel, matlab, activex

In MATLAB I am using ActiveX to import many columns of data from an excel file.  Each column is of a different and unknown length.  Therefore I do not know what cell range to put.

`Range = get(hSheet5, 'Range', '??:??');`

Is there a way for matlab to detect the length of the column so that I can then know what cell range to put when importing it?

Comment: I don't know what about Matlab and ActiveX, but in any form of integration with Excel there is a way to do this. In your worksheet object all you need to do is something like: `aWorksheetObject.UsedRange.Columns.Count` (or `Rows`). Not sure hoe relevant this is, so hope it helps.

Comment: Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244863/getting-the-number-of-filled-cells-in-a-column-vba might be useful to get the length of a particular column (it appears not to have an ActiveRange property, at least in python).

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke Yes, that is working.  However, it gives me the number of rows of the largest column on the worksheet.  Is there a way to modify it so that it gives me the number of rows of any column I want?

Comment: Have you looked at this post which suggests using something like `Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row` (or any top cell of an arbitrary column)? Does that work?

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke Oops!  What I meant to say is that yes, your suggestion (or rather the ones on the page you linked to) worked out the best.  The solution I used was `lastcol=hSheet6.Range(irange).End('xltoRight').Column`  (So I deleted my earlier comment).  Go ahead and put it as answer if you want.

Comment: Ah right, now I get it. Cool. All it took, really, was just a quick google search for an answer ;) Glad it works, though, good luck with finishing the project.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the solution should use ActiveX. I would do it with built-in function to read XLS file:

```
columnB = xlsread(fileName, sheetName, 'B:B');
```